# %-#s Tab Equivalent

Tags: php, string

I was using `%-70s` recently, and I was wondering if anyone knew if there is a tab space equivalent when using `%-#s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"HTML represents the horizontal tab as &#9; but as with all whitespace characters
this does not allow actual insertion of tabs into the page except inside
<pre></pre> tags or elements with CSS attribute white-space set to pre."
```

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key